# Service Provider (SP) initiated Single Sign-On (SSO) for integration with BANO

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are in the process of implementing a Service Provider (SP) initiated Single Sign-On (SSO) for integration with BANO. Can you point me to any official documentation or step-by-step resources for setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

We highly recommend reviewing the [Getting Started page for the Authentication Framework](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/getting-started/), especially the 1-minute video describing the gist of how it works.

That *Getting Started* page has a link to a quickstart for Banno's Consumer API, [Authentication (Node.js Example)](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/quickstarts/authentication/) which is a good starting point for seeing how authentication works when the user starts outside of the Banno digital banking UI.

- You can compare with how authentication works when the user starts inside of the Banno digital banking UI by reviewing the Plugin Framework's quickstart [Build Your First Plugin](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/quickstarts/buildyourfirstplugin/).

Either way, [signing up for a developer account on JackHenry.Dev](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/accessing-the-digital-toolkit/) is your best bet for getting comfortable trying out our APIs as you read the docs.